# Get the less-sold items with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have 2 objects (Order and Product) and a third (OrderDetail) that will be used as "navigation" between Products and Orders.

I'm trying to build a view that will show the less-sold products. For that I am "querying" the object OrderDetail and saving the result in a view model to later on be used in the view.

Model:

```
public class Product
{
  public int ProductID { get; set; }
  public string CodProduct { get; set; }
  public string Nome { get; set; }
  (...)
  public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
  public int OrderID { get; set; }
  (...)
  [BindNever]
  public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
  public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public int ProductID { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
  public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
  public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ProductSoldViewModel
{
    //Data from the Product
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    //Data from the OrderDetail
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult LSProducts()
{
   List<ProductSoldViewModel> model = new List<ProductSoldViewModel>();

   model = _context.OrderDetail
            .GroupBy(od => od.ProductID)
            .Select(o => new ProductSoldViewModel
            {
                ProductCode = o.Select(s => s.Product.CodProduct).FirstOrDefault(),
                ProductName = o.Select(s => s.Product.Nome).FirstOrDefault(),
                Qty = o.Sum(s => s.Quantity)
            })
         .OrderBy(od => od.Qty)
         .ToList();

   return View(model);
}
```

With this code, I get only the less-sold products that are present in the orders. But I need to get all the products, even those that have never been sold.

Can you give me some advice about how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should query the product table if you need to get all products:

```
public IActionResult LSProducts()
{
   List<ProductSoldViewModel> model = new List<ProductSoldViewModel>();

   model = _context.Product
            .Include(a => a.OrderDetails)
            .Select(o => new ProductSoldViewModel
            {
                ProductCode = o.CodProduct,
                ProductName = o.Nome,
                Qty = o.OrderDetails.Sum(s => s.Qty)
            })
         .OrderBy(od => od.Qty)
         .ToList();

   return View(model);
}
```

To avoid a null exception you may want to add the following constructor to your model:

```
public class Product
{
  public Product()
  {
     OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
  }

  (...)

  public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: it is giving me an error: "Product doesn't contain a definition for OrderDetail"...

Comment: I've updated the answer (OrderDetail -> OrderDetails)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!